# Vandermonde question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm studying time series analysis and in my book I came a cross with the following proof (The proof is actually the last page, but I posted as much information as possible on the problem):

[image]

I have highlighted the area I don't understand. The book tells reference where to look, but I can't find it... =( Can someone explain the last part of the proof of Proposition 1.2 in the picture I attached

Thank you for any help =)

P.S. If you can't see the image well enough, download it to computer =) Thank you =)

Comment: Your answer is found here: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde%27s_Matrix

Comment: P.S. If you can't be bothered to type out the question in a way that makes it easy to actually *read* it, why do you expect people to bother answering it? =) Thank you =)

Comment: Better.. Now how about stating *what* this is supposed to prove?

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answers =) I was lost with this one =)

Comment: +1 Sorry, I was in a hurry and just wanted to try my luck if someone knows the answer =) The red box highlighted the point I couldn't understand =)

Comment: where $\text{T}$ is given by $[1.\text{A}.4]$ and $[1.\text{A}.8]$.Writing out the first column of the matrix system of equations$[1.\text{A}.9]$ explicitly, we have 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1^{p-1} & \lambda_2^{p-1} & \cdots & \lambda_p^{p-1} \\
\lambda_1^{p-2} & \lambda_2^{p-2} & \cdots & \lambda_p^{p-2} \\
\lambda_1^{p-3} & \lambda_2^{p-3} & \cdots & \lambda_p^{p-3} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots &\vdots\\
\lambda_1^{1} & \lambda_2^{1} & \cdots & \lambda_p^{1} \\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
t^{11} \\
t^{21} \\
t^{31} \\
\vdots\\
\\
t^{p-1.1}\\
t^{p1}\\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$